# Import package when two bundles are exporting the same packages with different versions

Tags: java, osgi

I have three hypothetical bundles:

- bundleA exporting package1(2.0.0) and package2(1.0.0)
- bundleB exporting package1(1.0.0) and package2(2.0.0)
- bundleC importing package1(2.0.0) and package2(2.0.0)

When I run this, bundleC is importing packages package1(2.0.0) from bundleA, package2(2.0.0) from bundleB, but also package2(1.0.0) from bundleA. Why does this happen?

EDIT: This is what the OSGi console shows me:

```
Imported packages
anotherdualpackage; version="2.0.0"<bundleA_1.0.0.qualifier [5]>
dualpackage; version="2.0.0"<bundleB_1.0.0.qualifier [3]>
dualpackage; version="1.0.0"<bundleA_1.0.0.qualifier [5]>
```

Comment: bundleC cannot import package2 twice. This is not allowed by the spec.

Comment: That's what I thought, but somehow it's getting resolved anyway. (See my update)

Comment: I guess from OSGi version 4.3 containers work in the way that packages are resolved as capabilities. Question is: Is the "one imported package versoin rule" is applied to capabilities as well in OSGi spec?